# Removing default Virtualbox guest additions?

Tags: virtualbox, security, virtualization, guest-additions

I don't want guest additions.

I have Virtualbox on a Windows host running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as a guest. How do I make sure that all the guest additions are removed from the Ubuntu guest? I so far have run, in Terminal, these:

> dpkg -l | grep virtualbox

Which returned: unity-scope-virtualbox

> lsmod | grep -io vboxguest

Which returned: vboxguest

Although it doesn't show up as having the typical virtualbox guest additions, the Ubuntu screen size still resizes to the virtual machine's window. Is that actually a part of Ubuntu or from guest additions?

When first installed as a virtual machine, Ubuntu supports mouse pointer integration and screen (virtual machine window) resizing, which are typically from guest additions being installed.

Is there a way to remove the vboxguest kernel module as well?

Thank you.

Comment: How did you install them ? Did you reboot ? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31899/uninstalling-default-vboxguestadditions-on-debian

Comment: Look at Community answer to that issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Comment: Obvious question... why do you want to remove guest additions? VB won't run correctly without them.

Comment: I did not install them. I am looking to remove the ones that come with the initial install of Ubuntu. I'm trying to remove them for security, as I've heard it is better to have them removed for that.

Comment: So you could update VIrtualBox Guest Additions. It's better.

Comment: Having the guest additions installed definitely is better, though I am trying to remove the default ones for this.

Comment: @Smiith **you don't have to remove anything to install Guest Additions. Just install them and be done with it, if you expect VB to run properly with your host OS.**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From using the commands:

```
dpkg -l | grep virtualbox
ii  unity-scope-virtualbox      0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1      all    VirtualBox scope for Unity
```

And

```
lsmod | grep vboxguest
vboxguest   282624  6 vboxsf,vboxvideo
```

Since you want to remove these packages do as follows:

1. modules `vboxguest`:

   - Change into `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-<version_number>` folder

     ```
     cd /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-<version_number>
     ```
   - In there run:

     ```
     sudo ./uninstall.sh
     ```
2. For the guest additions `unity-scope-virtualbox`:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-query -s unity-scope-virtualbox

   Package: unity-scope-virtualbox
   Status: install ok installed
   Priority: optional
   Section: gnome
   Installed-Size: 77
   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
   Architecture: all
   Version: 0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1
   Replaces: unity-lens-vm
   Provides: unity-lens-vm
   Depends: python3, python3-gi, gir1.2-unity-5.0 (>= 7), gir1.2-dee-1.0 (>= 1.2.5), unity-scopes-runner, gir1.2-glib-2.0
   Conflicts: unity-lens-vm
   Description: VirtualBox scope for Unity
   This package contains the "virtualbox" scope which allows Unity
   to search for VirtualBox content.
   Original-Maintainer: David Callé <davidc@framli.eu>
   Homepage: https://launchpad.net/unity-scope-virtualbox
   ```

   - This is used by unity for search and probably be left alone.

Comment: If the module (vboxguest) is in use, how is it best to remove it? (Prevented from removing it because it was in use.  Is there a way to stop it from running so it can be removed?

Comment: @Smiith see updated answer for `how to`...

Comment: I went into /opt/VBox... folder and ran the uninstall.sh to uninstalled the vboxguestadditions. My problem is I opened the ova file in vmware and saw this "vbox kernel service is not running" warning at the start

Comment: @jcqian can you ask a new question?

Comment: This answer solved my problem. I was able to uninstall the vbox guest additions.

Comment: In 18.04, I don't find any folders under `/opt/`